# Online implementation of CryptoNight/R

Tags: mining, mining-theory, cryptonight

I'm on an adventure trying to write my own own implementation of a C CryptoNight/R hasher. I already have some working code but wanted something that could help me validate the hashes.
Is there any online CryptoNight/R hasher out there? If not, is there some code implemented somewhere that is easier to understand than the code in the monero-project on Github?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any web-based example but it's pretty easy to use [py-cryptonight](https://github.com/ph4r05/py-cryptonight) for testing/validation purposes.

For example:

```
pip install py-cryptonight
```

Then in Python:

```
import pycryptonight
import binascii

height = 123456
data = binascii.unhexlify('DEADBEEF')
prehashed = 0
variant = 5
hash = pycryptonight.cn_slow_hash(data, variant, prehashed, height)
print('Hash: {}'.format(binascii.hexlify(hash)))
```